# findViewById returns null in in 4.4.2 but works in 7.1.1

Tags: android, listview, android-appwidget

I am getting an error while deploying custom developed android app in APi version 19 (android 4.4.2). however, the same android app is successfully deployed on API 25 (android 7.1.1.)

so, when I debug the app I found out that below line throwing null error in APi 19 but no error in API 25 ( object is printed).

```
    searchView =(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_category);
    listViewCategories = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
```

searchview is android.support.v7.widget.

Comment: is your layout API specific?

Comment: Maybe you have different layout folder for specific API

Comment: The stacktrace would he helpful.

Comment: thank you very much. it was problem with layout file. both layout_23 and layout not in sync.